# RAM upgrade help

Tags: memory

I am lately experiencing RAM troubles on my PC and would like an upgrade.
PC is 5 years old, below you may find screenshot with stats.
Main usage is work: MS Office and statistical software.

I am looking for a upgrade to 16 or even 32GB but have no idea how to chose the memory.

I hope you could help me,

Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]